# Atomic elements selector engine

Tags: javascript, api

I've written a DOM element selector engine that I'm really quite happy with, and I'd love to hear some opinions on it from my fellow JavaScripters :D

It's called Atomic, and I've got a repository for it over at GitHub - and I've also included the code below...

Check it out (if you're in the mood) and let me know what you think. I'd appreciate any and all feedback!

```
/* Atomic Elements Selector Engine v0.1 (Beta)
    Copyright (c) 2012 Craig Pierce <craig@atomicjs.com>
    http://www.atomicjs.com */

/* THIS SOFTWARE HAS BEEN RELEASED IN "AS IS" CONDITION, WITHOUT ANY
    WARRANTY, AND IS AVAILABLE UNDER THE AS YOU WISH PUBLIC LICENSE. */

/* As You Wish Public License
    Copyright (c) 2012 Craig Pierce <craig@underctrl.com>
    http://www.underctrl.com/as-you-wish/

    Use and/or distribute exact copies of this license as you wish.

    Use and/or distribute exact copies of any works covered by this
    license as you wish.

    Modify any works covered by this license as you wish, so long
    as you:

        0. Retain for attribution all applicable copyrights and/or
            authorship notices.
        1. Use and/or distribute all resulting works under at least
            the same licenses as the originating work. */

;(function buildAtomicEngine(global, undefined){
    "use strict";

    var version = "0.1",

        dom = global.document,

        domReady = false,
        readyTimer = setInterval(checkDomReady, 50),
        readyCallbacks = [],

        atomicCache = {},

        cacheableRegex = /^(#document|body|html)$/i,
        readyStateRegex = /^(loaded|interactive|complete)$/i,
        commaSplitRegex = /\s*,\s*(?=(?:[^\)]|\([^\)]*\))*$)/,

        selectorReplaceRegex = new RegExp(
            "=([^'\"]+?)\\]|" +
            "\\[(.+?!=.+?)\\]|" +
            ":not\\((.+?,.+?)\\)|" +
            "^([>~\\s\\+])|" + 
            "([>~\\s\\+])$|" +
            ":(even|odd|selected|text|password|checkbox|radio|button|submit|reset|image|file|hidden)"
        , "gi");

    global.atomic = {
        version : version,
        options : {
            fallback : null,
            selectorOrder : false,
            useCache : true
        },
        ready : function (callback){
            domReady ? callback() : readyCallbacks.push(callback);
        },
        clearCache : function (){
            atomicCache = {};
        },
        get : function (selector, context, options){
            var defaults = global.atomic.options;

            if (!context){
                context = dom;
            }else if(!context.childNodes && context.length == undefined){
                options = context;
                context = dom;
            };

            options = (options || {});
            options.selectorOrder = (options.selectorOrder == undefined) ? defaults.selectorOrder : options.selectorOrder;
            options.useCache = (options.useCache == undefined) ? defaults.useCache : options.useCache;

            return getElements(selector.replace(selectorReplaceRegex, selectorReplace), context, options);
        }
    };

    if (dom.addEventListener){
        dom.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", handleDomReady, false);
        dom.addEventListener("load", handleDomReady, false);
    }else{
        dom.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", handleDomReady);
        dom.attachEvent("onload", handleDomReady);
    };

    function checkDomReady(){
        if (!domReady && readyStateRegex.test(dom.readyState)){
            handleDomReady();
        };
    };

    function handleDomReady(){
        if (!domReady){
            var x = -1,
                lenx = readyCallbacks.length;

            domReady = true;
            clearInterval(readyTimer);

            while (++x < lenx){
                readyCallbacks[x]();
            };

            readyCallbacks = null;
        };
    };

    function selectorReplace(match, capture1, capture2, capture3, capture4, capture5, capture6){
        var replacement = "",
            x = -1,
            lenx;

        if (capture1){
            replacement = ("='" + capture1 + "']");
        }else if (capture2){
            replacement = ":not([" + capture2.replace("!=", "=") + "])";
        }else if (capture3){
            var capture3Split = capture3.split(commaSplitRegex),
                append = "):not(";

            lenx = capture3Split.length;

            while (++x < lenx){
                replacement += (capture3Split[x] + append);
            };

            replacement = (":not(" + replacement.slice(0, -5));
        }else if (capture4){
            replacement = ("*" + capture4);
        }else if (capture5){
            replacement = (capture5 + "*");
        }else if (capture6){
            capture6 = capture6.toLowerCase();

            if (capture6 == "selected"){
                replacement = "[selected]";
            }else if (capture6 == "even" || capture6 == "odd"){
                replacement = (":nth-child(" + capture6 + ")");
            }else{
                replacement = ("[type='" + capture6 + "']");
            };
        };

        return replacement;
    };

    function getElements(selector, context, options){
        var atomicElements = [],

            selectors = selector.split(commaSplitRegex),
            x = -1,
            lenx = selectors.length,

            isDomOrder = (lenx == 1 || !options.selectorOrder),

            contextName = (context.nodeName || ""),

            isCacheable = cacheableRegex.test(contextName),
            useCache = (isCacheable && options.useCache),
            cacheKey = (selector + contextName + (isDomOrder ? "" : "sorder")),
            cacheItem = (useCache) ? atomicCache[cacheKey] : null;

        if (cacheItem){
            atomicElements = cacheItem;
        }else{
            var fallback = global.atomic.options.fallback,
                y = -1,
                leny = context.length;

            if (isDomOrder){
                if (contextName){
                    atomicElements = atomicDeduplicator(performSelection(selector, context, fallback));
                }else{
                    while (++y < leny){
                        atomicElements = atomicDeduplicator(performSelection(selector, context[y], fallback), atomicElements);
                    };

                    atomicElements.sort(byDomOrder);
                };
            }else{
                if (contextName){
                    while (++x < lenx){
                        var selectorX = selectors[x],
                            cacheKeyX = (selectorX + contextName),
                            cacheItemX = (useCache) ? atomicCache[cacheKeyX] : null,
                            atomicElementsX = (cacheItemX) ? cacheItemX : performSelection(selectorX, context, fallback);

                        atomicElements = atomicDeduplicator(atomicElementsX, atomicElements);

                        if (isCacheable && !cacheItemX){
                            atomicCache[cacheKeyX] = atomicDeduplicator(atomicElementsX).slice(0);
                        };
                    };
                }else{
                    context = atomicDeduplicator(context).sort(byDomOrder);

                    while (++x < lenx){
                        y = -1;

                        while (++y < leny){
                            atomicElements = atomicDeduplicator(performSelection(selectors[x], context[y], fallback), atomicElements);
                        };
                    };
                };
            };

            if (isCacheable){
                atomicCache[cacheKey] = atomicElements.slice(0);
            };
        };

        return atomicElements.slice(0);
    };

    function performSelection(selector, context, fallback){
        try{
            return context.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }catch (ex){
            if (fallback){
                return fallback(selector, context);
            };

            throw ex;
        };
    };

    function atomicDeduplicator(newElements, existingElements){
        var x = -1,
            lenx = newElements.length;

        if (existingElements && existingElements.length){
            var atomicElements = existingElements.slice(0),
                y,
                leny = atomicElements.length;

            loopx:
            while (++x < lenx){
                var element = newElements[x];

                y = -1;

                while (++y < leny){
                    if (element == atomicElements[y]){
                        continue loopx;
                    };
                };

                atomicElements.push(element);
            };

            return atomicElements;
        }else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(newElements).toLowerCase().indexOf("array") == -1){
            var atomicElements = new Array(lenx);

            while (++x < lenx){
                atomicElements[x] = newElements[x];
            };

            return atomicElements;
        }else{
            return newElements;
        };
    };

    function byDomOrder(x, y){
        return (x.compareDocumentPosition) ? (3 - (x.compareDocumentPosition(y) & 6)) : (x.sourceIndex - y.sourceIndex);
    };
})(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some things I noticed:

1. You don't need a semicolon after almost any case you use it after a `}` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/javascript-when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces ) - remove it after the `}` character in ALL cases except `atomicCache = {};`
2. I personally prefer spaces between braces and items (e.g. use `} else {` instead of `}else{` ) - and many other people do too, I hope...
3. `options = (options || {});` can be simplified to `options |= {};`
4. `lenx = readyCallbacks.length;` has incorrect tab spacing before it (typo)
5. It might be more clear to name the parameters `capture1`, `capture2`, etc something more clear - or write some comments on the if/then lines explaining each case
6. You might want to replace the `if (isCacheable)` items with `if (useCache)` to avoid populating your cache when it's not going to be used

(EDIT: accidentally put `?=` instead of `|=` for #3)